Angular Save Navigation Operator not working as expected
I'm running into an issue where the Safe Navigation Operator (?) is not working as intended.
task = {
    title: 'Review applications',
    assignee: null
};
test = this.task.assignee?.name;


Produces the following error:

TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'.

Current Environment

Angular CLI: 17.3.8
Node: 20.13.1
Package Manager: npm 10.5.2
Typescript: 5.4.2

I had done a search and found a similar issue, but it revolves around using an older version of typescript, of which I am using a newer version, and would think this issue would not exist at this time:

Angular gives an error when use safe navigation operator

Additional information on how Safe Navigation Operators should work can be found here:

https://docs.angular.lat/guide/template-expression-operators
Live Example: https://stackblitz.com/angular/apjvqexeoxn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
Within the Live Example:
File app.component.ts

Line 26:   nullItem = null;


File app.component.html

Line 52: <p>The null item's name is: {{nullItem?.name}}</p>


How can I solve this issue?

yea odd typescript seems to be incorrectly inferring a never type from that null -- wonder if defining an interface and declaring assignee as an optional prop might help typescript figure it out

I edited my question to add more context to how Angular's website says the operator should work.  Following their example, I get the same error.  While using an interface outlines the parameters of an object, the safe navigation operator I believe is supposed to account for unseen situations where an object parameters may be null

Ok, so my guidance was off, the link I was referring to is an out-of-date link from Angular 10... I wish I had read into it further.  But people are right in that it's not typical to use the safe navigation operator because of the use of interfaces.  However, turning off strict mode within the typescript.json file allowed for the "issue" to be resolved I guess.

Try defining the interface highlighting to typescript that value can be present or can be null! Else it will infer the type of assignee is null based on the value and this is giving you the error!
export interface Task {
    title: string;
    assignee: {name:string} | null;
}

task: Task = {
    title: 'Review applications',
    assignee: null
};
test = this.task.assignee?.name;


So this works. However, it sort of defeats the whole purpose of using the safe navigation operator.  I believe the purpose of using the safe navigation operator is to account for scenarios where an object might be of a type null even when we expect something to be in the object.  Sort of a way to try and catch scenarios that are not always accounted for.

Create an interface.
export interface IAssignee {
  name: string;
}

Now assign this.task.assignee to this interface. This is one way how you could do it:
test = (this.task.assignee as IAssignee).name;

If that doesn't work for you, try it with:
test = (this.task.assignee as unknown as IAssignee).name;

If you want, you could also do it without an interface:
test = (this.task.assignee as {name: string}).name;


This is along the same lines as the answer provided by Naren Murali, but I still don't believe this is how the safe navigation operator should work.

Please see again the error message. assignee is declared as 'never'. TS sees assignee as null and since null cannot have any properties, name remains as unknown to this object. That's why you should use an interface.

Hi @Reza Saadati, check out my post from an hour ago.  You are correct in the sense that an interface will help.  But the goal of the ? operator was to negate having to implicitly set data types for all object parameters.  I found that in the typescript.json file you can set strict to false wich allows the ? operator to now work, but it's not recommended.  It would definitely make sense to implement interfaces for data type adherence, but my guess is the ? operator was intended for situations prior to the implementation of interfaces to prevent crashing.

Ok, so my guidance was off.
The link I was referring to is an out-of-date link from Angular (latin even) 10... I wish I had read into it further...
But people are right in that it's not typical to use the safe navigation operator because of the use of interfaces. However, turning off strict mode within the typescript.json file allowed for the "issue" to be resolved.
